# Reference C++/CLI class in xaml static resources

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, c++-cli

I am currently developping an app for windows 8.1, I would like to insert a static c++ class

```
static ref class BooleanToVisibleConverter sealed : IValueConverter
```

into the resource list located in another xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibleConverter x:Key="BoolConvert"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

As hard as i keep trying, I keep getting the following error :
    The name "BooleanToVisibleConverter" does not exist in the namespace "Using:App15".

For information, "local:" refers to "Using:App15" which is the namespace of the c++ file.

I tried every namespace possible, there is no way i can manage to get this working by myself...

Comment: `c++` and `c++-cli` are two completely different languages.

Comment: c++-cli and c++/cx are two completely different language extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be other issues here (such as the namespace declarations in your XAML file), but two things jump out at me about your class definition:

- You need to declare your class public. `public ref class...`
- `static` doesn't do anything here.

  - You're probably getting a compiler warning about this: I got `warning C4091: 'static ' : ignored on left of 'BooleanToVisibleConverter' when no variable is declared`
  - It's not static in the C sense, where it only applies within the file where it appears.
  - It's not a static class (i.e., not insatiable) in the C# sense: `IValueConverter`s need to be instantiated to do their work, and C++/CLI uses a different syntax for that anyway.

Switch to `public ref class BooleanToVisibleConverter ...`, and see how that goes.

Comment: Switching to     public Doesnt change a thing. Doesn't the class need to be static for me to be able to retreive it in the resources ?

Comment: It isn't necessary to declare the class public (but it won't hurt), but it *must not be* static. Otherwise, you can't create an instance of it, which you want do in `<local:BooleanToVisibleConverter ... />`.